# WinDbg conditional breakpoint after .NET GC

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, windbg, conditional-breakpoint

I'm setting a conditional breakpoint at the end of a GC cycle.
The program breaks but it cannot evaluate the GcCondemnedGeneration variable so program breaks on every GC cycle regardless of the actual generation collected.

This is the breakpoint command:

```
> bp clr!ThreadSuspend::RestartEE ".if @@(clr!SVR::GCHeap::GcCondemnedGeneration==2) {kb} .else {g}"
```

This what I get when the breakpoint breaks:

```
Type information missing error for SVR::GCHeap::GcCondemnedGeneration
Couldn't resolve error at 'clr!SVR::GCHeap::GcCondemnedGeneration==2) {kb} .else {g}'
clr!ThreadSuspend::RestartEE:
00007fff`145d5dfc 488bc4          mov     rax,rsp
```

I tried all kind of variations but they all failed.
.Net version installed on the machine is 4.6.1.
My program runs with server gc.
clr.dll symbol was loaded successfully.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want a native callstack when GC ended? What's that useful for?

Comment: Although I was able to make it working, I would love to see the answer to @ThomasWeller question!

Comment: I'm not really interested in the callstack, I'm interested in dumping Gen2 immediately after GC gen2. The kb I used in the question is only for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make it working without using C++ expression syntax and just MASM expression (where `dwo` is used to derefence a DWORD-sized data such as `unsigned int`):

```
bp clr!ThreadSuspend::RestartEE ".if (poi(clr!SVR::GCHeap::GcCondemnedGeneration)==2) {kb} .else {g}"
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad,  
the variable is 'unsigned int' so why using poi?
When I removed the @@ and used dwo it worked.

?poi(clr!SVR::GCHeap::GcCondemnedGeneration) gives 4294967298 = 0000000100000002
While  ?dwo(clr!SVR::GCHeap::GcCondemnedGeneration) gives 2 = 0000000000000002

Comment: Right, sorry, my mistake!